# Is it possible to have a default button for each tab in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button

I use a `TabControl`
Each tab has its default button.
The first default button is working.
The second default button is a normal button.
How to fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could bind each Button's `IsDefault` property to its corresponding TabItem's `IsSelected` Property. Each time the selected tab item changes, another button would become the default, then.

Something like that:

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem x:Name="tab1" ... />
  <!-- ... other tabs ... -->
</TabControl>
<Button x:Name="button1" IsDefault="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=tab1}"/>
<!-- ... other buttons ... -->
```

Comment: Do you know the shortest way of doing that?